# Do I have to list modules in both `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and `/etc/rc.conf`?

Tags: linux, kernel, arch-linux, kernel-modules

I've added few modules into `mkinitcpio.conf`.

Are they automatically loaded at kernel boot or with `udev` if I don't specify them in modules list in `rc.conf`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modules listed in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` are included in the [intitrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) when it is generated with `mkinitcpio -p linux`. This loads the temporary filesystem into memory, and needs to include modules necessary to create this successfully, depending on your setup.

An example would be adding `raid1` to your modules line in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` to assemble a Raid1 array.

In your modules line in `/etc/rc.conf` you would only need to include modules that are not automatically loaded by `udev` but that you may require to run specific applications once your filesystems are mounted, such as `fuse` or `loop`.

**Note:** in the case of a Raid array, you would also include `USEDMRAID="yes"` in your `/etc/rc.conf`